# No GUI deleted dirs

Tags: 16.04, scripts, lightdm, shared-library

Running (was) 16.04 LTS on amd64 ssd 32gb hp insydeh20 bios

Lost X server so followed thread advising create new user profile which I did and it worked with  GUI back on

Couldn't access files from only SU profile so I shared them via properties

Then I deleted those (don't ask why)

Normal Boot hangs on a startup script re: dev mapper and cyptswap AppArmor is the first failed dependency of many GUI gone again

When booting recovery 4.4.0-38 I can get to tty e

If I run Sudo apt install returns disk is full and unable to lock files

I did a backup using deja dup and I can see it in recovery mode via ls and I can start duplicity albeit from there nothing as out of space 25gb of 25 in use

Comment: It **sounds** like you overwrote Windows? I don't know what **OD** means. With all of the problems you outline, I'd suggest that you just start all over. If you **did** overwrite Windows, restore it from the recovery partition and then reinstall Ubuntu **along side Windows**. If you don't want Windows (not recommended) then just wipe the drive entirely by writing out a new MBR/GPT partition table, and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. You may also wish to clean up your question so as to get better responses. Cheers, Al

Comment: If you do reinstall Windows, you may need to resize the partition down, to make room for Ubuntu. Don't use gparted to resize NTFS partitions. Use Windows own Disk Management application. ps: you still need to cleanup/simplify your question. Cheers, Al

Comment: I am certain I formatted my ssd to have 2 parts and one is named MBR the other I arbitrarily made an ext*? Yikes I don't know where I would get the new install if I have no OS to boot.  If I order a flash drive with 16.04 or Mint(?) will it work to create a clean install so I can start fresh?

Comment: You're confused. MBR is a partition table type, and probably incorrect if you've got a new UEFI computer, or a HDD 2TB or larger. You probably need a GPT partition table. I'd get to the BIOS device boot menu by holding down the function key outlined on the BIOS boot screen (F12?). Then see if you can select Windows restore first (you may not be able to do this because you wiped the drive). Then follow my previous instructions. ps: you can use the Ubuntu Live DVD or USB flash drive to reinstall Ubuntu (choose erase and install). Cheers, Al

Comment: I am able to get to TTY with root and I see using ls most everything is there when I try to run the return is this file or dir doesn't exist               I entered Sudo find and at least 1k lines with the data I need rapidly scrolled showing located in ./. USR/ETC/SHARED/ I cannot figure out how to make space or what came will undel debuggs returns something about a a small read occurred That's correct I am unable to load Windows. I can get to a TTY with root. How might I use my Ethernet and what commands to 1) clean space 2) get update

Comment: Not sufficient reputation will continue to search no vote option certainly would if I could!

Comment: Am I correct that 1) you don't want/need Windows, 2) you only have one 32GB SSD, 3) you have a UEFI computer (desktop or laptop?) 4) you have a Ubuntu Live DVD or USB flash key. Please advise. Cheers, Al

Comment: 1) correct 2) correct with 4gb memory and I have another 4 I can stick in 3) I am not certain and I am inclined to say BIOS /UEFI only shows up when I disable items in BiOs and enable legacy mode or if I wanted network boot 4) I have a USB san Cruzer 32gb with an image I downloaded of 14.04 (original download from windows of 16.04 showed up as CD-ROM install yet I have no optical (I do but not attached or used)

Comment: See my answer below. Please remember to vote/accept it if the information was useful. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically going to do a clean Ubuntu install.

1. If your USB flash key doesn't have 16.04.1 on it, then download that version and build it to your USB flash key.
2. Set your computer's BIOS to UEFI mode (not legacy).
3. Boot to your Ubuntu 16.04.1 Live USB flash key in "Try Ubuntu" mode. Start `gparted` from the Unity dashboard. Select /dev/sda (which should be your SSD) in the popup device selector. Go to the Device menu and select Create Partition Table. If you were able to set UEFI in your BIOS, select the GPT partition table. If you had to select legacy in your BIOS, select the MBR partition table. This step wipes out everything on the SSD.
4. Quit gparted, and double-click the "Install Ubuntu" icon on the desktop.
5. Install Ubuntu using the "erase and install" method. Do NOT create separate /home or /swap partitions. Recommend NOT selecting encryption.

ps: *for heaven's sake... don't start poking around in a working Ubuntu installation until you're more experienced.*

Report back how you did. Cheers, Al